# How to blend samples from multisample software rendering

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering, rasterizing, multisampling

please forgive any incorrect terminology, I'll do my best to explain.

I'd like to know how a rendering technology - gpu/cpu etc blends/merges the samples generated from multisample rendering? (Presumably over multiple passes.)
To be clear - I'm not asking for DirectX / OpenGL examples, I'm asking how it actually works.

Background: I've written a 2d polygon drawing function - in C/C++ -  which is based on the common model or dividing each horizontal scanline into multiple 'samples' (in my case 4) and then using this to estimate coverage. I clamp these points to 4 vertical positions as well, giving me a 4x4 grid of 'samples' per pixel.

I currently generate a bitmask mask per pixel of which 'samples' are covered and also an 'alpha' of how covered this pixel is from 0 to 256. This works perfectly with a single polygon and all the edges are nicely antialiased. The issue arises when drawing something like a pie chart, the first piece is drawn perfectly but the second piece which shares edges with it will draw over those edge pixels.

For example: [Multisample Grid Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6J7Z.png) in this picture my renderer will draw the orange section, and the bottom middle pixel will be 50% covered by this orange polygon, so will be 50% orange and 50% background colour (say black for instance). The green polygon will then be drawn and also cover the bottom middle pixel by 50% - so it will blend 50% green with the existing 50% orange and 50% black, giving us 50% green and 25% orange and 25% black - but realistically the black background colour should never come into it as the pixel is fully covered, just not by any one polygon.

This page describes the process and says ***"In situations like this OpenGL will use coverage percentages to blend the samples from the foreground polygon with the colors already in the framebuffer. For example, for the pixel in the bottom center of the image above, OpenGL will perform two samples in the green polygon, average those samples together, and then blend the resulting color 50% with the color already in the framebuffer for that pixel."*** but doesn't describe how that process actually works: https://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC420/chapter16/Chapter_16.html

I haven't posted source code because it's quite a large project and I'm not doing anything particularly different from most simple polygon renderers except split the main loop out to callback functions.

I can't switch up to a render buffer size 4xwidth and 4xheight as it's used for more than just polygon drawing. I'm happy to accept that all 'joined' polygons be known at function run time - such as the user being required to pass in all the pie chart polygons rather that one at a time as that seems a fair requirement.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Conceptually the color of each sample is stored and averaged to get the final pixel color. In practice GPUs use lossless compression to avoid the need for a color buffer 4x larger and this has dedicated hardware support to maintain performance.

Comment: you're saying don't use the actual rendertarget but instead, a small (1 row wide) buffer of 16 samples per pixel which starts off as a copy of the rendertarget and then after all polygons for this scanline are done you blend it with the background based on alpha/coverage?..  I was hoping to avoid doing alphablending where it isn't needed - ie currently solid 'span's are just written directly rather than blended as a speed optimisation.. also Im not sure how this would work for polygons which don't have an alpha of 100%.. for example textured areas

Comment: EDIT - of course - I just realised the alphablending of samples is handled perfectly because each sample starts off as whatever the background already was.

Comment: This is one of those 'secret sauce' parts of GPUs. When done right it's 'invisible' to the developer so GPU vendors go nuts on clever proprietary tricks to make this efficient. The details are pretty secret and may often be not super relevant to software implementations due to using a lot of hardware magic.

Comment: If you look at GPU rendering APIs, there is usually a concept of a 'Resolve' for a multisample render target that must happen before you can use it as a texture etc. which is when the GPU takes all the magic framebuffer compression and generates the final pixel value based on the individual sample values.